# LogManager.Configuration.FindRuleByName return null. NLog

Tags: c#, .net, xml, nlog

i have the rule

```
<targets >
    <target name="Global" xsi:type="File" fileName="Logs/GlobalLog.txt"  archiveNumbering="Date" enableArchiveFileCompression="true" archiveFileName="Archive/IPSlog.{#}.zip" archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" 
     maxArchiveDays="${logLifetime}"
    archiveEvery="Day" />
  </targets>
 <rules>
    <logger name="Global" minlevel="Trace"  writeTo="Global,Color" />
  </rules>
```

i tried change rule from code

```
 LogManager.Configuration.FindRuleByName("Global").EnableLoggingForLevels(loglevel, LogLevel.Fatal);
```

but FindRuleByName return null. where is my mistake?
Target finder works fine

```
    var target = (FileTarget)LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("Global");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rule:

```
<logger name="Global" minlevel="Trace"  writeTo="Global,Color" />
```

Specifies the following conditions:

- Logger must be named "Global". Ex. `NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("Global")`
- LogLevel must be Trace (or more servere)
- Write to the targets named `"Global"` and `"Color"`.

I guess what you want is this:

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace"  writeTo="Global,Color" ruleName="Global" />
```

- Logger can be any name because of `*`-wildcard. Ex. `NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()`.
- LogLevel must be Trace (or more servere)
- Write to the targets named `"Global"` and `"Color"`.
- Assign Logging-Rule-Name, so lookup is possible with `FindRuleByName`.

Notice you can also use NLog [Config-variables](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Var-Layout-Renderer) or NLog [Global-Diagnostic-Context](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Gdc-layout-renderer) to update the level-filter dynamically. See also:
https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages#semi-dynamic-routing-rules